# compare strings in flatlist

Tags: string, react-native, expo, react-native-flatlist

I am trying to compare a strings in a flatlist in a react native expo project but it is not working. item.bauteile_lage has strings like KG_1, KG_2, EG_1, EG_2 and so son.
I just want to see if item.bauteile_lage includes KG or EG.

Can anyone see what I am doing wrong?

```
<FlatList style={styles.FlatList}
 data={bauteile}
 scrollEnabled={false}
    keyExtractor={(item, index) => String(index) + item.value}
    renderItem={({item, index})=>   

<View>
    {item.bauteile_lage.includes("KG") ? 

        <View>
     
                 <View>
                 {z == 0 ? 
     
                        <View>
                            <Text>Bauteilbereich</Text>             
                        </View>:null 
                 } 

                 </View>


        </View>:null
                 
    
    } 
</View>
```

Comment: What is `z` in line z==0

Comment: the z has nothing to do with my problem. It is just checking if const z is still 0.

Comment: can you share a simple sample in snack expo